# Bind settings for LDAP authentication for moodle

Tags: authentication, ldap, moodle

I am now trying to configure for the LDAP authentication in `/admin/auth_config.php?auth=ldap`.

I would like to know what the `Bind settings` does? Is it necessary to fill in the DN and Password under `Bind settings` for LDAP to work?

And I have encountered an error code `auth_ldap_noconnect` when trying to sync the users through LDAP from the cron script. What could be the causes for this error?

Answer (score 0):

The Bind settings are necessary - without them Moodle can't connect to your LDAP server. They determine how Moodle will access the LDAP server.

```
CN = your Common Name
OU = your Organizational Unit
DC = your Domain Component
```

Those are all part of the LDAP data Interchange Format (LDIF) and they determine how the LDAP tree is filtered. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LDAP_Data_Interchange_Format.

So in Moodle you probably need a Distinguished name like:
cn=YourServiceAccountName,ou=YourSchool,ou=Service Accounts,DC=yourdc,DC=co,DC=uk

And you'll probably also have to list the Contexts where your students are found:
ou=yourschool,DC=yourdc,DC=co,DC=uk;

User attribute might = samaccountname (for MS Active Directory)